# Approximation of finite sume to the power of n

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a mathematical approximation for :

$(\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^i)^{p}$ where $x>1$

Comment: Make that an answer.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while writing the equation. Please check the modified equation.

Comment: Hi Alex! Alex here. Welcome to MSE, when you ask a question, you should provide what you're struggling at, instead of copy and pasting it like a homework problem.  You should also post what you've done :)

Comment: Since we can easily write down a simple formula for the exact value, 
$$\left(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)^p$$can you indicate what qualities the desired approximation should have?